# Waiting for multiple processes in bash with set -e

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I would like to run two processes in parallel, and have the script fail if either of the processes return non-zero. A minimal example of my initial attempt is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
(sleep 3 ; true ) &
(sleep 4 ; false ) &
wait %1 && wait %2
echo "Still here, exit code: $?"
```

As expected this doesn't print the message because `wait %1 && wait %2` fails and the script exits due to the `set -e`. However, if the `wait`s are reversed such that the first one has the non-zero status (`wait %2 && wait %1`), the message **is** printed:

```
$ bash wait_test.sh
Still here, exit code: 1
```

Putting each `wait` on its own line works as I want and exits the script if either of the processes fail, but the fact that it doesn't work with `&&` makes me suspect that I'm misunderstanding something here.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `bash` manual section about usage of `set`

> **-e** Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, **part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||**, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.  If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non- zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.

**tl;dr**

In a bash script, for a command list like this

```
command1 && command2
```

`command1` is run in a separate environment, so it cannot affect the script's execution environment. but `command2` is run in the current environment, so it can affect

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't expecting the failure of one of the commands inside the `&&` list to cause the script to exit, but had assumed that if the list as a whole evaluated to non-zero then it would. An even more minimal example shows that that's wrong though: `false && true` doesn't exit, which isn't what I'd expect from that documentation. Putting it in a subshell `(false && true)` behaves as expected, I guess because the whole command no longer counts as being part of a `&&` list.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want quite elegantly with **GNU Parallel** and its *"fail handling"*.

In general, it will run as many jobs in parallel as you have CPU cores.

In your case, try this, which says *"exit with failed status if one or more jobs failed"*:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | parallel --halt soon,fail=1  
echo Job 1; exit 0
echo Job 2; exit 1
EOF
echo GNU Parallel exit status: $?
```

**Sample Output**

```
Job 1
Job 2
parallel: This job failed:
echo Job 2; exit 1
GNU Parallel exit status: 1
```

---

Now run it such that no job fails:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF | parallel --halt soon,fail=1  
echo Job 1; exit 0
echo Job 2; exit 0
EOF
echo GNU Parallel exit status: $?
```

**Sample Output**

```
Job 1
Job 2
GNU Parallel exit status: 0
```

---

If you dislike the `heredoc` syntax, you can put the list of jobs in a file called `jobs.txt` like this:

```
echo Job 1; exit 0
echo Job 2; exit 0
```

Then run with:

```
parallel --halt soon,fail=1 < jobs.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I noticed that a lot of similar questions had answers that suggested GNU Parallel and it does indeed look awesome, but unfortunately this script needs to work in a Windows developer environment under git-bash. Even if it's possible to get Parallel working in Windows, I can't really justify a change in our dev environment just for what I hoped would be a simple way of speeding up one specific bottleneck in one script.

Comment: Fair enough. It was just something I thought worth mentioning. It may help someone else. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @bmerrihort If GNU Parallel does work under git-bash on Windows, consider using `parallel --embed`. That way you are still only talking about a single script.