# Bash parallel execution and exit code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-sem

I would like to run multiple commands in parallel in a bash script, but if any of these commands fails (returns a non-zero exit code), the script exit code must be non-zero.

I have tried to use `sem` (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html):

```sh
cat >script.sh <<EOF
sem -j+0 "sleep 2; echo 1"
sem -j+0 "sleep 4; exit 1; echo 2"
sem -j+0 "sleep 6; echo 3"
sem --wait
EOF
bash script.sh; echo $?
```

and just background the process:

```sh
cat >script.sh <<EOF
{sleep 2; echo 1} &
{sleep 4; exit 1; echo 2} &
{sleep 6; echo 3} &
wait
EOF
bash script.sh; echo $?
```

In both cases, the overall exit code is always 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) ?

Comment: Is sem a wrapper of parallel?

Comment: What is `sem`? Do you have any reference? Note that you tagged `sem`, which is `SEM stands for search engine marketing. Google Adwords is one of the most common ways of SEM`.

Comment: It's the exit code of `wait`. From wait man page EXIT STATUS section: "0   The wait utility was invoked with no operands and all process IDs known by  the  invoking shell have terminated."

Comment: `sem` is a symlink to **GNU Parallel** that makes it act like a semaphore shared across processes.

Comment: Do you want the running/remaining jobs killed when one fails? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200984/2836621

Comment: It seems rather hopeful to believe the `echo` will run if you do `exit 1; echo 2`

Comment: If you use a one-line compound statement surrounded by curly braces, you need spaces beside them and a semi-colon after the last.

Comment: @KamilCuk As @MarkSetchell says: the symlink of `sem` makes it run as if you ran `parallel --semaphore` (it is just so fricking long to write).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if any of these commands fails (returns a non-zero exit code), the script exit code must be non-zero.

So write that condition.

```
childs=();
{ sleep 0.2; echo 1 ;} &
childs+=($!);
{ sleep 0.4; exit 1; echo 2; } &
childs+=($!);
{ sleep 0.6; echo 3; } &
childs+=($!);

ret=0;
for i in "${childs[@]}"; do
     if ! wait "$i"; then ret=1; fi
done
echo "ret=$ret"
exit "$ret"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everybody for their answers.

Following [Mark Setchell's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200984/320399), I think the best solution for me is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

cat <<EOF | parallel --halt 1
date; sleep 2; date; echo -e "1\n"
date; sleep 4; exit 1; date; echo -e "2\n"
date; sleep 6; date; echo -e "3\n"
EOF
```